# Android - Importing contacts through vCards via ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am currently trying to automate some Android actions through ADB and getting stuck with the contact import through vCards. There are 2 ways of doing this :

1. automate the exact "tappings" of the user, which supposes you have to determine the position of each "button" according to the screen resolution, etc. It is what I have done right now but it really seem hard to maintain, since there are too much parameters to take into account (custom roms, wierd resolutions, portrait/landscape mod, etc).
2. find what's happening when you click on "import contact from vCards" and do this action through ADB

Basically, I would like to apply the 2nd option, but I don't know what is happening when you click on "import contacts from vCard", which I would need to call the same action/intent from ADB. Any idea on the ADB command I should execute ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this. Update `-d` option with correct `vcf` path.

```
adb shell am start -t "text/x-vcard" -d "file:///sdcard/contacts.vcf" -a android.intent.action.VIEW com.android.contacts
```

- Mime Type : `text/vcard` or `text/x-vcard`
- URI: path to vcard
- Action: `android.intent.action.VIEW`
- Package: `com.android.contacts`

Comment: @Manish, I did try below command to import contacts using adb command through .vcf file saved on device in a folder "abc"

Comment: command: adb shell am start -t "text/x-vcard" -d "/sdcard/abc/31Contacts.vcf" -a android.intent.action.VIEW com.android.contacts
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/sdcard/abc/31Contacts.vcf typ=text/x-vcard pkg=com.android.contacts launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/sdcard/abc/31Contacts.vcf ty
p=text/x-vcard flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.contacts launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }

Comment: what is difference beetween `text/vcard` and `text/x-vcard`

Comment: @Manju transfer the .vcf file to the emulator/phone then import it. If you try to directly do it from the pc(according to **@Nomenator**) it does'nt work.

Comment: this fails when the default application for vcf files has not been selected

Comment: how to disable the prompt dialog and import contacts without blocking UI

Answer (score 2):

Selected answer didn't work for me. I needed that functionality for several specific tests. So what I did is added Override BeforeSuite to test class inside which I called methods from the below classes and called super class method after.

```
public class AdbUtils {
private static final String CH_DIR = "cd ";
private static final String LOCATE_ADB = "locate -r ~/\".*platform-tools/adb\"";

public static void createContacts(List<Contact> contacts) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
        if (i < contacts.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println(executeCommand(AdbCommands.CREATE_AND_SAVE_CONTACT
                    .getCommand(new String[]{contacts.get(i).getName(), contacts.get(i).getPhoneNumber()})));
        } else {
            System.out.println(executeCommand(AdbCommands.CREATE_AND_SAVE_CONTACT
                    .getCommand(new String[]{contacts.get(i).getName(), contacts.get(i).getPhoneNumber()})));
            System.out.println(executeCommand(AdbCommands.START_CONTACTS_APP_LIST_STATE.getCommand(null)
                    + " && " + AdbCommands.SLEEP.getCommand(new String[]{"3"})
                    + " && " + AdbCommands.PRESS_BACK_BUTTON.getCommand(null)));
        }
    }
}

public static void removeAllContacts() {
   System.out.println("DEBUG - Delete all contacts: " + executeCommand(new String[]{AdbCommands.DELETE_ALL_CONTACTS_CMD.getCommand(null)}));
}

private static String executeCommand(String command) {
    return executeCommand(new String[]{command});
}

private static String executeCommand(String[] commandLines) {
    String adbDir = locatePlatformToolsAdb();
    adbDir = adbDir.substring(0, adbDir.length() - 4);

    String[] command = new String[commandLines.length + 2];
    command[0] = "bash";
    command[1] = "-c";
    commandLines[0] = CH_DIR + adbDir + " && " + commandLines[0];
    System.arraycopy(commandLines, 0, command, 2, commandLines.length + 2 - 2);

    String input;
    String errorInput = null;
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec(command);
        proc.waitFor();

        input = parseInputStream(proc.getInputStream());
        errorInput = parseInputStream(proc.getErrorStream());
        proc.destroy();
        return input;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return errorInput;
}

private static String locatePlatformToolsAdb() {
    String path = null;
    String error = null;
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", LOCATE_ADB});
        proc.waitFor();

        path = parseInputStream(proc.getInputStream());
        error = parseInputStream(proc.getErrorStream());
        proc.destroy();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(null != path){
        System.out.println("DEBUG - Located platform tools: " + path);
        return path;
    }
    else throw new IllegalStateException("DEBUG - error locating adb: " + error);
}

private static String parseInputStream(InputStream input) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            resultBuilder.append(line);
        }

        return resultBuilder.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

and

```
public enum AdbCommands {

WAIT("./adb shell wait"),
SLEEP("./adb shell sleep %s"),
DELETE_ALL_CONTACTS_CMD("./adb shell pm clear com.android.providers.contacts"),
START_CONTACTS_APP_LIST_STATE("./adb shell am start com.android.contacts"),
PRESS_RECENT_BUTTON("./adb shell input keyevent 187"),
PRESS_HOME_BUTTON("./adb shell input keyevent 3"),
PRESS_BACK_BUTTON("./adb shell input keyevent 4"),
CREATE_CONTACT("./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact " + "-e name '%s' -e phone %s"),
CREATE_AND_SAVE_CONTACT(CREATE_CONTACT.getCommand(null) + " && ./" + SLEEP.getCommand(new String[]{"3"})
        + " && ./" + PRESS_RECENT_BUTTON.getCommand(null) + " && ./" + SLEEP.getCommand(new String[]{"3"})
        + " && ./" + PRESS_RECENT_BUTTON.getCommand(null) + " && ./" + SLEEP.getCommand(new String[]{"3"})
        + " && ./" + PRESS_BACK_BUTTON.getCommand(null) + " && ./" + SLEEP.getCommand(new String[]{"3"}));

private String command;
private static final String arg = "%s";

AdbCommands(String command){ this.command = command; }

public String getCommand(@Nullable String[] args){
    String command = this.command;
    if(null == args) {
        return this.command;
    }
    else{
        if(countSubstring(this.command, arg) != args.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong args count!");
        for (String arg : args) {
            command = command.replaceFirst(AdbCommands.arg, arg);
        }
        return command;
    }
}

private int countSubstring(String str, final String subStr){
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(lastIndex != -1){
        lastIndex = str.indexOf(subStr,lastIndex);
        if(lastIndex != -1){
            count ++;
            lastIndex += subStr.length();
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}