# adb pull working with emulator but not with usb connectd devices

Tags: android, adb, pull

Following commands are working with emulator but not with the usb connected devices.

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts /home/Temp
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony /home/Temp 
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.media /home/Temp 
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.settings /home/Temp
```

where `/home/Temp` is my destination directory. I want similar commands to work with usb connected devices. Suggest alternatives ASAP.

Comment: Due to security reasons, these would not work in original devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security reasons, you cannot access these from original devices. Only rooted devices may provide such permissions.

To view contacts, refer [Android - Importing contacts through vCards via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488290/android-importing-contacts-through-vcards-via-adb)

These other references might be useful:

- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25646/how-do-i-backup-data-sms-contacts-from-a-device-with-a-broken-screen

Comment: @PratikDesarda: You can accept it as answer by clicking the grey tick mark next to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use adb pull to pull data from devices. You need to have root access to be able to do this.