# Can I Run .vcf File With adb & C#

Tags: c#, android, adb, contacts, vcf-vcard

I pushed a *.vcf* file from my PC to Android device; I want to run this file and import all contacts to the device using adb shell.

This is my C# function:

```
private void adbcommand (string command)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.FileName = @"D:\ADB\adb.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = command;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();


            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            process.Close();
        }
```

Comment: i want to import vcf file in my phone no't in my c# project,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488290/android-importing-contacts-through-vcards-via-adb

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            adbcommand("shell pm clear com.android.providers.contacts");

            adbcommand("shell mkdir /sdcard/contacts/");
            string contactsFilePath = @"D:\mycontact.vcf";
            adbcommand("push "+ contactsFilePath + " /sdcard/contacts/");
            adbcommand("shell am start -t text/x-vcard -d file:///sdcard/contacts/mycontact.vcf -a android.intent.action.VIEW com.android.contacts");

private void adbcommand (string command)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.FileName = @"D:\ADB\adb.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = command;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();


            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            process.Close();
        }

    }
```