# Add dynamic Contacts to android emulator or device from command line

Tags: android, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, adb

We want to add specific contacts to our android emulator/device so that we can run tests particularly invites on those contacts. The contacts would be generated as pre-script before running tests. As of now we are trying create a vcf file and upload it. Then importing using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488290/android-importing-contacts-through-vcards-via-adb). But it doesn't work any more. Getting toast message `could't import vCard` and a device notification as `I/O error`. I am sure the vCard is correct format as I can import manually. And path is also correct as I can use same command to open an image file uploaded similarly.

We want the contacts to be added via script without any manual intervention.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore... like starting from some Android version?

Comment: @Lino not sure from which android version. I am trying on Android 11. It is not working

Comment: It would be great if you can perform a quick analysis on the different android versions otherwise it will be quite challenging to spot the issue